# Problems running large command line program (Inkscape) in Azure Function app or App Service

Tags: azure, azure-functions, inkscape

I wasn't sure whether to ask this in an Inkscape specific forum or here in Azure. I tagged both.

My goal is to run a windows build of Inkscape in a cloud function preferably or in an App Service to open up different vector files and send them back to the user as a plain SVG.

I've downloaded the binary archive (https://inkscape.org/en/release/0.92.2/windows/32-bit/) and extracted it in Kudu on both a paid App Service and in a Function App.

When I run `inkview.com` it seems to be working. It outputs info to cmd

But when I run `inkscape.com` it just stays open for a couple of seconds and quits. (Just outputs a blank line and exits) I've tried `-V` and `-?` and many other commands (also using the `-Z` without GUI command).

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on here? Is Azure perhaps missing some dependencies that Inkscape needs to run? Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions, like WebApps and Mobile Apps, run in an App Service. The App Service runs in a secure environment called a sandbox which imposes certain limitation. Amongst them, is the use of GDI+.

With Inkspace being a graphics program, I can only imagine that it is making use of GDI+, so it would be blocked.

You can see the list of limitation https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

In order to be able to run inkspace in Azure, you need to host in something other than App Service, such as a VM, Cloud Service, Service Fabric, Containers... etc.

Comment: Aha, I see. Thank you! I will investigate using a dedicated VM instead.